# How does c# create an instance of Array abstract class behind the scene for arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, abstract

### I mean what happens when we initialize this syntactic sugar?

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Comment: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSwG4CGATpgHYCuAWwBGAU04BnTAF5eIgO6YwPYAG0AuoUwIANJji70uqgF8A3MxLHUxoA) -- it compiles to a call to [`RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.initializearray?view=netframework-4.8), passing it a reference to data stored directly in the module

Comment: it will use the [`newarr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr?view=netframework-4.8) opcode to create a new array instance. Arrays are one of the primitive types (like `Int32`, etc), and the CLR knows how to create and use them.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, you can use [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSwG4CGATpgHYCuAWwBGAU04BnTAF5eIgO6YwPYAG0AuoUwIANJji70uqgF8A3MxLHUxoA) to see the generated IL.

I recommend [HOW C# ARRAY INITIALIZERS WORK](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/21/how-c-array-initializers-work.aspx) article to appreciate the details.
In particular:

- it allocates a temporary array (to ensure that assignment is atomic)
- it calls `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array, valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)`
- the value passed in to the above method comes from internal class called containing a private nested struct called `__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16`
- after the call, the initialized temporary is assigned to numbers variable.